# Ошибка Cannot convert 'AnsiString *' to 'AnsiString'

Tags: c++, c++builder

Как исправить ошибку?

> Cannot convert 'AnsiString *' to 'AnsiString'

в программе:

```
AnsiString stroka,vyhod;
stroka = Edit1->Text;
int l,i,j,k;
l=stroka.Length();
vyhod = stroka[1];
AnsiString *vn = new AnsiString[l];
for(i=1;i<=l;i++){
vn[i]=stroka[l-i];
}

Edit1->Text=vn;
```

Comment: А вы можете сами себе объяснить, почему вы написали это предложение AnsiString *vn = new AnsiString[l];? Лично я, например, его смысла совершенно не понимаю.

Comment: Надо создать AnsiString фиксированой длинны

Answer (score 2):

Я не понимаю, зачем вы динамически выделяете массив строк, тем не менее, я думаю, что вы имели в виду

```
AnsiString *vn = new AnsiString( l );
                               ^^^^^
```

вместо

```
AnsiString *vn = new AnsiString[l];
                               ^^^
```

при условии, что класс `AnsiString` имеет конструктор с одним параметром, который задает число символов в строке.

И в последующем цикле вы должны написать либо

```
( *vn )[i] = stroka[l-i];
```

либо

```
vn->operator []( i ) = stroka[l-i];
```

Хотя и в этом случае не понятен смысл выделение объекта типа `AnsiString` в динамической памяти.

Сам цикл также вызывает большие сомнения, даже если синтаксически его корректно написать

```
for(i=1;i<=l;i++){
( *vn )[i]=stroka[l-i];
}
```

У объекта `stroke`  индекс меняется от `l-1` до `0`, тогда как у строки, адресуемой указателем с таинственным именем `vn` индекс меняется от `1` до `l`. Если вы хотите реверсировать строку, до вам следует написать цикл корректно.

Answer (score -1):

Заменил на такое:

```
AnsiString stroka, vyhod;
stroka = Edit1->Text;
int l, i;
vyhod = "";
l = stroka.Length();
for (i=0; i<=l-1; i++) {
    vyhod += stroka[l-i];
}
Edit1->Text = vyhod;
```

Comment: Мы тут до сих пор не поняли, это решение задачи или дополнение...